# How To Increase Max_Allowed_Packet In Mysql In Windows 8 I Tried Editing .Ini File But It Prompts "Access Is Denied"

Tags: mysql

Please don't tell me to google. I have been searching solution for this, for several days. I tried editing .ini file, it prompts access in denied. And if i try to chnage using command prompt that also it does no allow me to do so.I cannot even use "Show Max_allowed_packets". It says show is not recognized as internal and external command.

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....


# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

this is my .ini file

Comment: You should use any editor like notepad++, sublime etc to edit this ini file. Have your tried any or used notepad ? [**NOTE**: before editing just make copy of this .ini file. ]

Comment: Yeah. i edited using notepad only, and i did make a copy of this. But after editing in notepad, when i save, it prompts access denied.

Comment: Well, how about editing it as an administrator, since then you will have access?

Comment: Open the file, save it in different place and paste in the mysql configuration folder (with mysql stopped). That should normally do it.

Comment: hey, i added max_allowed_packet = 16M, after runing notepad as administrator.then i used this command running cmd also as administrator.  but still i have errror while uploading that increase max_allowed_packet ...                                                          "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --install

Answer (score 0):

@user2243471, follow one from below steps to edit `.ini file` in *windows 8*:

1. Use one of those editors I mentioned. ( notepad++ / sublime text 3 / brackets )
2. And if you want to open in default notepad then run notepad as **"Run as Administrator"** using right click on it and then make edition and save the file.

Comment: thanks a lot. I was able to edit .ini file. But do i need to again start mysql so that the changes are effected?

Comment: @user2243471, I glad its works. Accept answer for others clarification. And yes its better to restart.

Comment: if tried to stop mysql but,                                                               C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6>net stop
The syntax of this command is:

NET STOP
service

Comment: i added max_allowed_packet = 16M, after runing notepad as administrator.then i used this command running cmd also as administrator. but still i have errror while uploading that increase max_allowed_packet ... "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --install